# I can't get d3 transition to work with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm putting together a test program to learn d3.js. However I can't seem to get transitions to work. I've been through the documentation several times and can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

I assume it's something to do with using transition along with requestAnimationFrame, but no combination of search terms is providing me a useful answer. Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong?

```
        (function(){
        "use strict";
        var randArray = [];

        (function randomWalk(){
            for(var i=0;i<5;i++) randArray[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 10) % 2? randArray[i]+1 || Math.round(Math.random() * 10) : randArray[i]-1 || Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
            setTimeout(randomWalk,800);
        })();

        (function update(){
            var d3 = window.d3 || {},
                mySelection = d3.select("div#container").selectAll("div").data(randArray);
                mySelection.enter().append("div").text(function(d){return ""+d;});
                mySelection.text(function(d){return ""+d;}).transition().style('padding-bottom',function(d,i){return (d*2.5)+'em'});

            requestAnimationFrame(update);
        })();

    })();
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Racheet/bPfFY/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it! The fiddle you posted was missing a period before 'transition()':

```
mySelection.enter().append("div")
   .text(function(d){return ""+d;})
   .transition().style('padding-bottom',function(d,i){return (d*2.5)+'em'});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bPfFY/2/

Currently, there is only one transition as the page loads. If you want the bars to change every half second you'll need to update the value of randArray when update is called.

Edit: After reading your comments, I've updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bPfFY/3/

I changed a couple of things trying to get it to work, but basically '.enter()' is used only when adding elements to the page from '.data()'. When we called update a second time, the divs already exist and there is nothing in the '.enter()' selection (more on this: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)

When update() is called, we should just select the already existing div elements, update their data values and use the new values to redraw text and the padding:

```
d3.select("div#container")
        .selectAll("div").data(randArray)
    .text(function(d){return ""+d;})
        .transition().duration(500)
    .style('padding-bottom', function(d, i){return (d*2.5 + 'px');});
```

I also changed the requestAnimationFrame(update) to setTimeout(update, 1000). d3 doesn't chain animations so it is usually best to make sure one is completed (with the '.duration(500)') before starting another.

Comment: Thanks! the missing period was a type into jsfiddle, it's present in my actual code. The actual result I'm looking for is what you get from that fiddle if you strip the .transition() call. RandArray is automatically updating every 800 milliseconds, and I'm trying to make the bars smoothly transition to match it. I've gotten as far as making them transition to match it, but the smoothly seems to be beyond me. That's why I was using the transition() call.  Are you suggesting that I call the randArray update from within the graph update function?

Comment: The randomwalk function is just being used to mock arbitrary data coming over a websocket. Which is why I'm trying to find a solution where the graph and data update independantly but still have a data-join.

Comment: When I first answered I didn't look closely at randomWalk(); just saw the missing period and thought was causing your problem.

Comment: It's understandable, my question could have been better worded. Thanks for your help.